# How to remove an item from a list that isn't chosen by random.choice

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make this script choose a random value from the 'avengers' and 'villians' list. I have done that, and I have chosen a random value between those to be deemed the winner. What I am trying to do is make it so the winner stays in the list, and the loser is removed from the list. (Ex: if 'selectedAvenger' wins, 'selectedVillian' will be removed from the 'villians' list, and vice versa. (Small project for programming class)

```py
import random # imports the random module

avengers = ['Thor', 'Iron Man', 'Spiderman', 'Hulk', 'Falcon', 'Black Widow', 'Antman', 'Captain America']
verb = ['smashed', 'kicked', 'slapped', 'bonked']
villian = []
# these are the lists that the script will use

for i in range(8):
    villian.append(input('Enter villian number ' + str(i + 1))) # asks user to list 8 villians

print('Welcome to Avengers: End of Line!') # welcomes the user
input('Press "Enter" to continue.') # asks the user to press the enter key to continue the script

selectedAvenger = random.choice(avengers) # selects a random avenger
selectedVillian = random.choice(villian) # selects a random villian
selectedVerb = random.choice(verb) # selects a random verb

winner = random.choice([selectedAvenger, selectedVillian])


print(winner)
```

Comment: so your trying to make a list containing only the winner?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Do you want to remove _all_ the heroes/villains/verbs that weren't selected?  Or just one of each at random?

Comment: sorry if i was unclear, in the line where it selects a winner, i want it to remove the one that isnt selected. meaning if the 'selectedVillian' wins i want the 'selectedAvenger' to be removed and vice versa

Comment: `if winner == selectedAvenger: villain.remove(selectedVillain) else: avengers.remove(selectedAvenger)`

Comment: check out `list.remove`.  I would also advise picking a random integer 0 or 1 as your index into `combatants = [selectedAvenger, selectedVillan]` and then calling either `avengers.remove` or `villans.remove` depending on your random index.

Comment: aye thanks my dudes! been stuck on this for a minute

Comment: @JohnGordon -- unless an Avenger and a Villain have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a populated list of villains? I think I might not have understood your question correctly, but here is the solution as I understand it.

```
if winner == selectedAvenger:
    villian.remove(selectedVillian)
else:
    avengers.removed(selectedAvenger)
```

Comment: I don't think this works if an Avenger and a Villain have the same name.  I'd advise picking a random index instead.